# a relaxed and calm feeling after an intense practice?

Tags: training, forms, muay-thai, relaxation, awareness

okay so here how it goes:

I did some punching and kicking practice. after that I took a shower and after that I suddenly felt a little different I was very clam and relaxed full of awareness. I felt like I was in a different state. The feeling lasted I think for 20 minutes at least and then after some time I was back to normal again.

I have this kind of experience before but it happens with me when I meditate but today I did nothing like this. Just wanted to ask if this is normal and if anyone else has also experienced same thing?

I have heard some stuff where martial arts is related with energy like yin and yang but I never really paid attention to it neither I understood it.

Can someone can explain what really happened with me?
I have been practising for more than 4 months but never experienced anything like this usually I feel tired after practice.

Can this experience happen again?
I mean I really liked whatever it was and if yes then how can i achieve it every time?

Comment: Endorphins. Not sure what the question actually *is*, though, since "normal" is more or less meaningless when talking about things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magic is not real, so I am afraid that ying/yang energy is out.

It is most likely that [endorphins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorphins) are being released after exercise.  They can also be released during meditation.